# How to use for loop in mongoose find function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop, mongoose

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/update', async (req, res, done) => {
  let drive = req.app.get('drive');
  let fileId = req.body.id;
  let subject = req.body.subject;
  let grade = req.body.grade;
  let industry = req.body.industry;
  await TagFile.findOne({id: fileId}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    //console.log(res);
    //console.log(subject);
    takeRes(res);
  })
  function takeRes(res) {
    for (let i = 0; i > subject.length; i++) {
      if(!res[0].subject.includes(subject[i])) {
        res[0].subject.push(subject[i]);
        console.log(res[0].subject)
        console.log("first was called")
      }
      else {
        console.log(res[0].subject)
        console.log("else was called.")
      }      
    }
  }
})
```

This is a post request that is made from my site. When it gets to the step where the for loop needs to be used, I don't get anything in the console from the if else statements. I know this probably has something to do with async, but I don't fully understand it, and would love a push in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: What does `res` give to you when you console logged it?

Comment: When outside of the for loop, I get the result I need. Within the for loop though, I don't get anything. Not even an "res is undefined", just nothing shows up in the for loop. Any ideas? @luckongas

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `await` you don't need to use the `callback` function. Use following snippet to query with mongoose, rest of the parts depends on your business logic:

```
const res = await TagFile.findOne({id: fileId}).exec();
takeRes(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

result of `findOne()` is `object` and result of `find()` is `array` and when you use `findOne()` the `res[0]` is incorrect and you can use `lean()`to convert model to object, so use find like this:

```
let res = await TagFile.find({ id: fileId }).lean();

for (let i = 0; i > subject.length; i++) {
  if (!res[0].subject.includes(subject[i])) {
    res[0].subject.push(subject[i]);
    console.log(res[0].subject);
    console.log("first was called");
  } else {
    console.log(res[0].subject);
    console.log("else was called.");
  }
}
```

when you use `findOne` try like this:

```
let res = await TagFile.findOne({ id: fileId });

for (let i = 0; i > subject.length; i++) {
  if (!res.subject.includes(subject[i])) {
    res.subject.push(subject[i]);
    console.log(resizeTo.subject);
    console.log("first was called");
  } else {
    console.log(res.subject);
    console.log("else was called.");
  }
}
```